# Changing the maximum length of a varchar column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, varchar

I'm trying to update the length of a varchar column from 255 characters to 500 without losing the contents. I've dropped and re-created tables before but I've never been exposed to the alter statement which is what I believe I need to use to do this. I found the documentation here: [ALTER TABLE (Transfact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) however I can't make heads or tails of it.

I have the following so far (essentially nothing unfortunately):

```
alter table [progennet_dev].PROGEN.LE
alter column UR_VALUE_3
```

How do I approach this? Is there better documentation for this statement out there (I did some searches for an example statement but came up empty)?

Comment: In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, you can also right-click a table and select "Design" to open the design view. From here you are presented with a list of each column in the table, with each column's respective data type listed next to it. You can modify the value here. However, this method will drop the table and rebuild/readd it, IIRC.

Answer (score 486, accepted):

You need

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn <<new_datatype>> [NULL | NOT NULL]
```

But remember to specify `NOT NULL` explicitly if desired.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn VARCHAR (500) NOT NULL;
```

If you leave it unspecified as below...

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn VARCHAR (500);
```

Then the column will default to allowing nulls even if it was originally defined as `NOT NULL`. i.e. omitting the specification in an `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN` is always treated as.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn VARCHAR (500) NULL;
```

This behaviour is different from that used for new columns created with `ALTER TABLE` (or at `CREATE TABLE` time). There the default nullability depends on the [`ANSI_NULL_DFLT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187375.aspx) settings.

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of adding '[NOT] NULL' here? Just curios why your answer had this an Mitch's doesn't?

Comment: @MitchWheat - ["ANSI_NULL defaults are always on for ALTER COLUMN; if not specified, the column is nullable."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

Comment: So [NOT NULL] specifies that NULL values -cannot- be placed in the column?

Comment: @Michael - Without the square brackets, yes. The square brackets indicate that bit of syntax is optional. If you omit it allowing `NULL` is the default.

Comment: have to say i keep trying this and continue to get the error                     Error code 30000, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "varchar" at line 2, column 20.

Comment: @Kdean571 - Seems like you are using Derby from that error message. This syntax is SQL Server.

Comment: sorted it :)..ALTER COLUMN MY_COL SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(100)

Answer (score 29):

Increasing column size with `ALTER` will not lose any data:

```
alter table [progennet_dev].PROGEN.LE 
    alter column UR_VALUE_3 varchar(500)
```

As @Martin points out, remember to explicitly specify `NULL | NOT NULL`

Answer (score 29):

For MySQL or DBMSes other than MSSQL, you may need to use `modify` instead of `alter` for the column value:

```
ALTER TABLE `table name` 
MODIFY COLUMN `column name` varchar("length");
```

For MSSQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `table name` 
ALTER COLUMN `column name` varchar("length");
```

Comment: That's what was already posted. Is there something new you'd like to share?

Comment: Also it works for MySQL and this question is tagged [TSQL] so it's in the wrong place

Comment: MODIFY is what's new.  ALTER COLUMN gave me a syntax error but MODIFY COLUMN worked for me with no problems.

Comment: @KGBird - because you aren't using SQL Server. `MODIFY` is syntax for some other database system than the question was about

Answer (score 10):

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME MODIFY COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(40);
```

I am using **Oracle SQL Developer** and @anonymous' answer was the closest, but kept receiving syntax errors until I edited the query to this. I changed `alter` to `modify` and there's no need to define `column_name` as `column`.

Answer (score 3):

Using Maria-DB and DB-Navigator tool inside IntelliJ, *MODIFY Column* worked for me instead of *Alter Column*

Comment: What new does this post add to the answer provided by @Mitch Wheat on Jan 12 '12 at 1:37?

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle SQL Developer

ALTER TABLE car_details MODIFY torque VARCHAR(100);

Comment: This just repeats/rehashes Jett's answer from August 2019.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having above doubt, what worked for me is

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` CHANGE `property` `property` 
VARCHAR(whatever_you_want) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in db2:

```
alter table "JOBS"  alter column "JOB_TITLE" set  data type varchar(30);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can save old data and create a new table with new parameters.

[image: see image]

In SQL Server Management Studio: "your database" => task => generatescripts => select specific database object => "your table" => advanced => types of data to script - schema and data => generate

Personally, I did so.

Answer (score -1):

For MariaDB, use **modify column**:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN column_name VARCHAR (500);
```

It will work.

Comment: The question is about SQL server